# How to get the last nodes of a Treeview?

Tags: vb.net, treeview, treenode, axwindowsmediaplayer

So... I have a treeview that basically represents a playlist, and I want to get the `nodes` on the last level (the songs) to get their `text` and be able to create a Playlist for a `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` in the order the songs appear in the `treeview`, the treeview has categories, for example, by year, by album, by artist, the songs will always be on the last level, although the last level will no be always the same. How could I get the last level nodes? Thank you.

```
  -- Artist
       --> ALbum
           --> Song1
           --> Song2
           --> Song3
       --> album2
           --> Song1
           --> Song2
  -- Artist2
       --> ALbum1
           --> Song1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make nodes searchable by setting its [name / key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.name(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
'                    key         text
albumNode.Nodes.Add("Song", "Name of song 1")
albumNode.Nodes.Add("Song", "Name of song 2")
albumNode.Nodes.Add("Song", "Name of song 3")
```

To find all nodes with the key "Song":

```
Dim songNodes As TreeNode() = myTreeView.Nodes.Find("Song", searchAllChildren:=True)
```

Here's an example:

```
Using view As New TreeView

    For i As Integer = 1 To 2
       'Add a new artist node with the key "Artist"
        With view.Nodes.Add("Artist", String.Format("Artist {0}", i))
            Debug.WriteLine(.Text)
            For j As Integer = 1 To 2
               'Add a new album node with the key "Album"
                With .Nodes.Add("Album", String.Format("Album {0}-{1}", i, j))
                    Debug.WriteLine("    " & .Text)
                    For k As Integer = 1 To 3
                       'Add a new song node with the key "Song"
                        With .Nodes.Add("Song", String.Format("Song {0}-{1}-{2}", i, j, k))
                            Debug.WriteLine("        " & .Text)
                        End With
                    Next
                End With
            Next
        End With
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine("")
    Debug.WriteLine("Nodes with ""Song"" key:")
    Debug.WriteLine("")

    For Each node As TreeNode In view.Nodes.Find("Song", searchAllChildren:=True)
        Debug.WriteLine(node.Text)
    Next

End Using
```

Output to the Immediate Window:

```
Artist 1
    Album 1-1
        Song 1-1-1
        Song 1-1-2
        Song 1-1-3
    Album 1-2
        Song 1-2-1
        Song 1-2-2
        Song 1-2-3
Artist 2
    Album 2-1
        Song 2-1-1
        Song 2-1-2
        Song 2-1-3
    Album 2-2
        Song 2-2-1
        Song 2-2-2
        Song 2-2-3

Nodes with "Song" key:

Song 1-1-1
Song 1-1-2
Song 1-1-3
Song 1-2-1
Song 1-2-2
Song 1-2-3
Song 2-1-1
Song 2-1-2
Song 2-1-3
Song 2-2-1
Song 2-2-2
Song 2-2-3
```